# Amazon S3 bucket policy for hosting a static website and blacklist IPs

Tags: amazon-s3

How can I set up a bucket policy in S3 to allow static website hosting while restricting some IPs to access the files?

For reference, this is the bucket policy example for static webhosting:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a [condition](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition) for denying certain IP addresses or a range of IP addresses. For [example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/ExampleIAMPolicies.html#iampolicy-example-sourceip) this may be used:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[{
    "Sid":"PublicReadGetObject",
        "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
         "NotIpAddress": {
            "aws:SourceIp": ["200.1.11.123"]
         }
       }
    }
  ]
}
```